# change background colour depending on checkbox selection and save html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm still in he early process of leaning jquery so be gentle.

Please see attached code:

html:

```
<div id="page-container" class="green-background">

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" class="form1" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="background" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="background" value="red">Red<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div><!-- /#page-container -->
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var searchText = 'blue';

 $('.form1 input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  var dummy = $(this).val() === searchText;
}
$(this).removeClass('blue-background');
});});
```

By default, the page-container will have a green-background classname, if i select the blue radio button, it will change the classname to blue-background. I also want the html to save so that blue background will then be the default. I can't seem to get my jquery working.

Comment: How do you mean 'save'?  Do you mean that the user will reload the page and come back and see a blue background?

Comment: @ntgCleaner yes both examples do exactly what, but i want it to write to the html file and replace the class so it will no be blue-background or red-background.

Comment: It seems that you're going to have to write a cookie for that user.  Rewriting the file every time a user clicks save probably wouldn't be efficient.  If you're making it so all users can change a singular background, you may have to save that information into a database.  Look into jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/5jqbR/2/
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[type=radio]').on("change", function(){
        //$(this) is equal to whatever your selected.
        var valueClass = $(this).val(); //get the new css color from the value field on the radio
        $('#page-container').removeClass(); //removes all classes from the div
        $('#page-container').addClass(valueClass); //set the new click
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" class="form1" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="background" value="blue-background">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="background" value="red-background">Red<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
```

You were almost there. I think you over thought it. Just remember your selectors. You don't need to check which one is ":checked" because you are binding to all of them but it will only fire on the one you change.

Comment: your example works very well to a point, it does exactly what i asked but it does not save the html file meaning when you reload the page, it's back to the green-background class, i would like the class to be changed to red-background or blue-background depending on what was selected.

Comment: You would need to post the form to a database or some sort of server variable. Javascript in general only modifies the users DOM. It does not change the source(server side) html. So when the page is refreshed it is set back to the original. You going to need to do some sort of server side scripting(php, .net, etc..) in order to do this.

Comment: Hi Tony and thanks for your input, i'm very new to this so is this something you can hep me along with?

Comment: Its really your decesion/your hosting company. No matter what scripting language you choose your host/server has to support it. 2 of the most popular right now are Php and Asp.net.(by no means am I saying these are your only options before every fanboi of their favorite language gets crazy. Php is typically setup in a Linux Environment with a MySql DB and ASP.Net is in a Windows Environment and is written in C#(mostly some VB) and you can use Microsoft SQL Server. Php is free, ASP.Net Visual Studio has a Free express version, that is pretty good. You have to decided what you want to do.

Comment: I'm a .NET guy myself. Mainly because of my job. I used to do PHP but now .NET is what I enjoy the most.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great case where we can use the .attr() function. You can use attr to select any attribute in a HTML element including class. The syntax is $('your_element').attr(var1,var2);

var1:your attribute e.g.(name,class,src,id)

var2:value(this is only used for changing the attribute)

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8vF3/

HTML:

```
<body id="body1" class="green-background">
    <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" class="form1" method="get">
       <input type="radio" name="background" value="blue-background">Blue
       <br>
       <input type="radio" name="background" value="red-background">Red
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').on("change", function () {
        var radio_name = $(this).val(); //get the value of radio button
        $('#body1').attr('class', radio_name); //changes class to radio value
    });
});
```

Comment: your example works very well to a point, it does exactly what i asked but it does not save the html file meaning when you reload the page, it's back to the green-background class, i would like the class to be changed to red-background or blue-background depending on what was selected.

Comment: You cannot do that with Javascript. You could do it in PHP.